# how to fix error on a null object reference?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

UPDATE! 12/03

Database parameters:

```
class IS4(context: Context, name : String?, factory:SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version : Int) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {
```

Error present when importing DB

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXZL0.png)

Well I was trying to finish my crud but I'm blocked into that error, when i try to open the layout he close and sends me that error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jetpackteste/com.example.jetpackteste.create_cliente_upd}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3447)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2146)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.jetpackteste.create_cliente_upd.deleteData(create_cliente_upd.kt:62)
    at com.example.jetpackteste.create_cliente_upd.onCreate(create_cliente_upd.kt:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7981)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7970)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

**The problem:**

When i run the program he crash when i open the layout create_clients_upd

**Database delete fun**

```
fun deleteData(codigo_cliente: String) : Int {

    val db = this.writableDatabase
    return  db.delete(CLIENTES_TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", arrayOf(codigo_cliente))
}
```

Layout classe create_cliente_upd

```
internal var helper = IS4(this)






override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val clientes = intent.extras?.getParcelable<clientes>("cliente_key")

    deleteData()


    //comando fullscreen

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_cliente_upd)

    fillDatas(clientes)

    //apresenta na imagem a toolbar para voltar atras


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar_activity)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}

fun deleteData(){
    delete_button.setOnClickListener{

        helper.deleteData(IDinput_upd.text.toString())
    }
}
```

the button is in the same layout but he don't recognize him

Comment: where do you bind the button? If you're binding it in the same file maybe the scope is wrong.

Comment: i was not binding because it says : val cannot be reassign

Comment: Either bind the view where you declare it or change the _val_ to _var_ so you can reassign it when you need to.

Comment: the problem is , he has no declaration , because it's a button not a val , the only think i did was create the id for the button and created the binding in the kotlin  ... or i'm making confusion?

Comment: in Kotlin you would bind a button like so: val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_name) You could also use var instead of val. The latter makes the object final, the former allows for mutability, meaning you can reassign it as many times as you want

Comment: haaa! i understand know ! it worked , but now he presents another error can u see it pls? i updated my question. what parameters i should use?

Comment: It looks as if the IS4 should include more parameters. Go to its declaration and see what else you should be passing in there other than context

Comment: i don't know which parameters i should put , cause the parameters where created for the database and he asks for the factory, name and version , he doesn't need that in that layout

Comment: can u call me in the chat? pls

Comment: I'm at work, so I can't chat now, sorry. From the developer's guide, it seems that you can use the following: internal var helper = IS4(this, null, null, 1) as your first default helper. Here is the link with the explanations on all the parameters: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)

Comment: thks the button worked ! i just need to configure correctly the class to delete , and will work thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_cliente_upd)`
  line before calling deleteData function. As IDinput_upd is initialized after setContentView method.

Comment: in that case i dont need the findView?

Comment: You should read the following article.
https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set an id to delete_button in the layout file it's located like this:

```
android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
```

Then you need to use the function find view by id to get an instance before setting the click listener so you can work with it in your code:

```
delete_button = findViewById(R.id.btn_delete)
```

Comment: it says : val cannot be reassign